# Preguntas de opinión y debates

Tags: discusión

En general, soy nuevo dentro de la comunidad (cuenta antigua, poco uso) y la verdad es que muchas veces me encuentro con la situación de que tengo dudas sobre cuestiones que no podrían aparecer en el foro de stackoverflow porque se considerarían "opinión", sin embargo, considero que en muchas ocasiones, los testimonios de otros programadores y su punto de vista pueden ser extraordinariamente valiosos

¿Cuál sería el foro adecuado dentro de stackoverflow para generar este tipo de preguntas?

¿Es correcto cerrar preguntas como opinión aunque estas opiniones tengan un alto valor añadido?

Un saludo a todos.

Comment: Podés visitar el chat! Y si, si una pregunta no encaja con la tematica del sitio, se cierra.

Comment: Hm... aunque es cierto que seguramente desde el chat pudiese obtener las respuestas a mis preguntas y generar un debate como comentas, la idea sería que ese "debate" de opinión pudiera quedar guardado dentro de stackoverflow ya que realmente pueden ser extremadamente útiles. En caso de que estas preguntas no tengan cabida dentro de stackoverflow, la cuestión sería si este foro sería una posible solución para ello o si por el contrario no hay lugar para ellas en stackoverflow (que tampoco sería un problema)

Comment: Toma en cuenta que [es.so] **no es un foro**. Es un sitio Q&A (preguntas y respuestas) y tiene una dinámica particular distinta de los foros. Así son todos los sitos pertencientes a la red Stack Exchange. Por lo tanto, **no existe foro adecuado** dentro de la red de Stack Exchange para el tipo de preguntas que planteas.

Comment: En ese caso por mi perfecto, simplemente quería saber si me estoy perdiendo algo, y, como comento, no me parece que sea un problema, aunque creo que es una necesidad que tenemos muchos programadores y lamentablemente no hay grandes foros en español que centralicen este tipo de discusiones.

Comment: Yo pienso que hay que reinventarse, no es que en el sitio sobren preguntas, tampoco se ve que estén subiendo las visitas y con la llegada de las IA's posiblemente habrá  un bajón progresivo. Así como en el inicio del sitio se era más permisivos con el tipo de preguntas, creo que debemos volver a ese camino. Preguntas del tipo `Por que se dice que no se debe usar eval en js?`, `Es bueno este patrón para X caso`. He visto varias preguntas que piden un feedback al modelo ER, a mi me parecen perfectas preguntas.

Comment: Incluso recomendaciones "necesito una librería para exportar a excel", oye quien no ha necesitado exportar a excel?? y existen tantas. Creo que una respuesta que diga yo he ocupado las librerías A, B y C y la que me ha dado mejores resultados es la B, es una respuesta muy útil.

Comment: a mi también me gustaría, pero la verdad es que la respuesta de mauricio al menos a mi me parece perfecta, otra cosa es si hay que plantear una nueva opción o un cambio de paradigma, pero considero que es harina de otro costal. Lo que si que creo que es cierto es que sin esa característica adicional,  en cuando otro foro la ofrezca, mucho trafico se redirigira hacia allí